# Differences in terminal prompt for different users on server

Tags: unix, terminal, vps

I am build a Digital Ocean VPS for my site but got a weird little problem.

If I `ssh root@<ip here>` and sign in, I get a terminal prompt of `root@<hostname>:~#` and things like tab completion etc work nicely.

If I `ssh deploy@<ip here>`, (`deploy` is just another user I have made) and sign in, The terminal prompt is just `$` and when I try using tab to autocomplete paths it just moves the cursor about 2 tab widths away from where it was and doesn't autofill. Also when I use the `up` cursor key to view past commands run, I get `^[[A^` outputted.

Any idea what is wrong with my `deploy` user and thoughts on how it can be fixed? I'm not a hugely competent unix user so i'm a bit stuck. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered on IRC, but for the record:

It seems the `root` user has a bash-like shell assigned which has tab completion enabled, whereas the `deploy` user has the more stand `sh` as its shell.  This can be confirmed by checking `/etc/passwd` for the two users.

If that is the case, simply use `vipw` or `usermod -s /path/to/bash deploy` to change the deploy user's shell to, in the example, bash (substitute your favorite shell as necessary).